# Error: The superclass, 'PictureProvider<AdvancedNetworkSvg>', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments. Flutter_advanced_networkimage

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a project that was working fine, but after the flutter update,
i got many errors because of the outdated podfile, that i tried to solve with some
recommandations found on different blogs.

now i have this as the current last error i have to solve,

Has anybody faced this problem with a Flutter app please?

```
../../../Flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter_advanced_networkimage-f0f599fb89c494d9158fb6f13d4870582f8ecfcb/lib/src/provider/flutter_advanced_networksvg.dart:17:9: Error: The superclass, 'PictureProvider<AdvancedNetworkSvg>', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  const AdvancedNetworkSvg(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

my pubspec.yaml looks like this fr this dependency

```
flutter_advanced_networkimage: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/mchome/flutter_advanced_networkimage
      ref: master
```